# How can I query TFS to get the latest of a specific work item?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Consider the following hierarchy:

1 Test Case work item has multiple Test Result work items.  I can make a "Work Items and Direct Links" query in TFS, to show me this hierarchy:

> Test Case "Customer needs to blabla"
>       - Test Result - Fail on 1/11//11*
>       - Test Result - Success on 2/1/11*
>       - Test Result - Success on 3/1/11*

Is it possible to limit the query result to the latest Test Result? So I would like to have this:

> Test Case "Customer needs to blabla"
>       - Test Result - Success on 3/1/11*

Note that I cannot filter on the State field, because those fields are not maintained...

*Euro date notation d/mm/yy

Comment: I think it is not possible using the standard workitem query, but you should be able to achieve it using Excel or Reporting Server. Would that work for you?

Comment: We didn't really find a decent way to do this either in VS or in Excel. We resorted to a custom solution: An app that queries TFS for the necessary workitems. Thanks for your input anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using WIQL. You would have to do it programmatically to filter after the initial query I'm afraid.

Comment: Wow, *the*  Martin Woodward answers my question, great! :-) We've indeed realized this is impossible, and wrote a simple app which does this for us. Thanks anyway! 
Taking advantage of this opportunity, sorry, but can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review ? ;-)