# Code Review Information - TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I was wondering if it was possible to query TFS for information regarding code reviews. Specifically I want to get information related to how long it takes reviewers to complete reviews from the time the review is submitted, what reviewers give what answers (Looks Good, Needs Work, etc.) most frequently, what projects get the most reviews etc.

Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio Online?

Comment: SO is for questions about *programming, actual codes*.

Comment: @L.B: it's also about tools used uniquely by programmers, and TFS in general, but code reviews in particular, should be on topic.

Comment: @JohnSaunders `Is there a way to do this in Visual Studio Online?` How can a question about *how to use a tool* be on topic here?,

Comment: @L.B: it's how to use a tool for Software Engineering. Any such question is on topic.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Using the same logic, it uses Sharepoint (Maybe completely implemented on it) I will vote to migrate there then :)

Comment: @L.B: Visual Studio Online has nothing to do with SharePoint. And, BTW, SharePoint development is on topic here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I meant TFS...(and as you said if OP asks something related with coding on SharePoint, of course this is the right place, but not how to use some menus of some tools)

Comment: @L.B: you're wrong about that, and should maybe ask on [meta].

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'll leave [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) for you.

Comment: @L.B: I won't be doing that. I know I'm right.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Me too.

Comment: @L.B: question was already asked and answered: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204647/are-tfs-support-questions-on-topic

Comment: @JohnSaunders I am still not convinced. Only one answer. I wait for posts with more discussions :)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't understand what you mean, but anyway, sorry for taking your time, you have to edit many more titles.

Comment: @L.B: I mean there are a large number of TFS questions. They are not all about writing TFS code. Many are about _using_ TFS.

Comment: It's about API and their features: it has my vote.

Comment: You may find [this discussion][1] useful.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review

Comment: @GiulioVian exactly :) OP posts some codes and asks where he/she got stuck. Not like "*which menu do you use to change the default font of notepad*" as in this question