# TFS + Git : Custom work item (ReviewOutput)

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I would like to create something like "Review Output" work item.

I'm using Git as VersionControl and of Visual Studio Online as TFS server.

Is there a way to create field with Git Commit ID in WIT template?

Additionally it would be perfect if I can create List of items in WIT template.

Maybe you have experience with reviewing changes with Git & TFS and you have another idea, how to handle "code bugs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally what a "Pull Request" workflow is for. It captures both review comments, the commit and other data you may be interested in,

But to answer your question, you can link a Git commit to a work item from Web Access *only*:

[image]

The "List of items" you're looking for is not possible using standard work item controls. The Visual Studio Code Review feature for TFVC uses a different control to capture the review comments in the IDE.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435088/736079

You could do the same thing, but would need to create a Team explorer Add-in to capture the review comments.

I wouldn't take this step and wait to see if TFS 2015 will cover your needs out-of-the-box.

Comment: Do you know when TFS 2015 will be officially pushed to VSO?

Comment: VSO will always be ahead of TFS 2015

Comment: PS: Have you checked out: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/11/01/collaborative-commenting.aspx

Comment: Yes, but like it's saying: It's not a code review directly. It's just to get other user know about your comments.