# Get TFS code review comments report given for files

Tags: tfs

```
        We used TFS query option to get code review comments report, But 
we are not able to get TFS code review comments report given for files.

        It is possible to get report by TFS query option / TFS REST API.
```

[image]

```
    Many thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither Work item query nor rest API is  able to retrieve code review comments for now. However you can achieve your goal by using **TFS API**.

Specifically the comments are accessible via the [DiscussionThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread.aspx) class. Just need to query discussions using [IDiscussionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.idiscussionmanager.aspx).
Sample code as below:

```
 public List<CodeReviewComment> GetCodeReviewComments(int workItemId)
 {
        List<CodeReviewComment> comments = new List<CodeReviewComment>();

        Uri uri = new Uri(URL_TO_TFS_COLLECTION);
        TeamFoundationDiscussionService service = new TeamFoundationDiscussionService();
        service.Initialize(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri));
        IDiscussionManager discussionManager = service.CreateDiscussionManager();

        IAsyncResult result = discussionManager.BeginQueryByCodeReviewRequest(workItemId, QueryStoreOptions.ServerAndLocal, new AsyncCallback(CallCompletedCallback), null);
        var output = discussionManager.EndQueryByCodeReviewRequest(result);

        foreach (DiscussionThread thread in output)
        {
            if (thread.RootComment != null)
            {
                CodeReviewComment comment = new CodeReviewComment();
                comment.Author = thread.RootComment.Author.DisplayName;
                comment.Comment = thread.RootComment.Content;
                comment.PublishDate = thread.RootComment.PublishedDate.ToShortDateString();
                comment.ItemName = thread.ItemPath;
                comments.Add(comment);
            }
        }

        return comments;
    }

    static void CallCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Handle error conditions here
    }

    public class CodeReviewComment
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

More details please refer this similar question: [Using TFS API, how can I find the comments which were made on a Code Review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will check the solution you had provided.