# Team foundation server - retrieving review comments

Tags: tfs

I am trying to retrive the review comments for all my code reviews fromthe TFS.
I am not able to build the query. My parameters are as below. I do not get anything from this :-(

```
Team Project = @Project
And    Work Item Type     In Group    Code Review Response Category
And    Requested By          =        @Me
Or     Requested By       Was Ever    @Me
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work item query is not able to retrieve code review comments, you can achieve your goal by using TFS API. [This case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review) provides a solution, you can check it:

You should be able to get to code review comments with functionality in the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.aspx) namespace.

Specifically the comments are accessible via the [DiscussionThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread.aspx) class. And you should be able to query discussions using [IDiscussionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.idiscussionmanager.aspx).

Code snippet is as below:

```
 public List<CodeReviewComment> GetCodeReviewComments(int workItemId)
 {
        List<CodeReviewComment> comments = new List<CodeReviewComment>();

        Uri uri = new Uri(URL_TO_TFS_COLLECTION);
        TeamFoundationDiscussionService service = new TeamFoundationDiscussionService();
        service.Initialize(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri));
        IDiscussionManager discussionManager = service.CreateDiscussionManager();

        IAsyncResult result = discussionManager.BeginQueryByCodeReviewRequest(workItemId, QueryStoreOptions.ServerAndLocal, new AsyncCallback(CallCompletedCallback), null);
        var output = discussionManager.EndQueryByCodeReviewRequest(result);

        foreach (DiscussionThread thread in output)
        {
            if (thread.RootComment != null)
            {
                CodeReviewComment comment = new CodeReviewComment();
                comment.Author = thread.RootComment.Author.DisplayName;
                comment.Comment = thread.RootComment.Content;
                comment.PublishDate = thread.RootComment.PublishedDate.ToShortDateString();
                comment.ItemName = thread.ItemPath;
                comments.Add(comment);
            }
        }

        return comments;
    }

    static void CallCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Handle error conditions here
    }

    public class CodeReviewComment
    {
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
    }
```