# Is it possible to ADD comments to code reviews via the TFS API?

Tags: tfs

I can see from [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review) that you can read comments from a code review stored in TFS.  Is it possible to ADD comments to a code review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly you can have a try with the [DiscussionThread.AddComment Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396).

There is a thread with the discussion about this topic here :
[TFS API Copy Comments from one DiscussionThread to another](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90e9e4e7-9927-4c83-94fd-6ca7586b3d95/tfs-api-copy-comments-from-one-discussionthread-to-another?forum=tfsworkitemtracking)

Comment: Thanks for your help