# Using TFS API, how can I find the status of code review like "Looks Good", "Needs work"?

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

I searched the discussions already and have tried this,

```
Changeset changeSet = _versionControlServer.GetChangeset(Int32.Parse(changesetString));
                            if (changeSet != null)
                            {


                                foreach (var item in changeSet.AssociatedWorkItems)
                                {
                                    WorkItem wk = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(item.Id);
```

But I cannot find a public property from `WorkItem` that says "Finished(Looks Good)".

Is there a way to find this through the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of work items comes to code reviews: **Code Review Request**
,**Code Review Response**.

> When you ask for a review, TFS creates a Code Review Request, and then
>   behind the scenes creates one Code Review Response for every person
>   you’ve asked to review my work. So if you tag Alice, Bob, and Charlie
>   on my review, there are four work items created for me: one request
>   plus three responses.
>
> The glue is something called a **Related Link**. The parent review
>   relates to the children responses and vice versa. This simplifies
>   things a bit because once you have the review, you can easily
>   determine the response work items based on their IDs.

The code you are trying to get the work item is Code Review Request. What you want to find is a filed called **Closed Status** in Code Review Response:

> The status selected by the reviewer when closing the code review
>   request. The number is stored in the system and written to the data
>   warehouse as follows:
>
> - 0 â€“ Not Reviewed
> - 1 - Looks Good
> - 2 - With Comments
> - 3- Needs Work
> - 4 - Declined
> - 5 - Removed
>
> Reference name=`Microsoft.VSTS.CodeReview.ClosedStatus`
>
> *[Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/guidance-code-review-feedback-field-reference)*

You could use WIQL combine with TFS API to fetch what you need. Details steps please refer this tutorial: **[Getting Code Review Statistics Programmatically from TFS](https://www.geoffmazeroff.com/2016/04/10/getting-code-review-statistics-programmatically-from-tfs/)**

More example of accessing code reviews with TFS API is shown here: [Using TFS API, how can I find the comments which were made on a Code Review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who needs it,

```
 foreach (WorkItem wr in workitems)
            {

            string shelvsetValue = null;
            string codeState = null;
            string userName = wr.CreatedBy.ToString();
            foreach(Field f in wr.Fields)
            {
                if(f.Name.Equals("Associated Context"))
                {
                    shelvsetValue = f.Value.ToString();
                }
                if (f.Name.Equals("Closed Status Code"))
                {
                    if(f.Value!=null)
                    { 
                        codeState = f.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```