# Get Code Review comments history from TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2019

[image: TFS code review comments]
I am using TFS 2018 On Premise.

Is there any way to get the list of review comments (like shown in Visual studio)  using api or using TFS query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063271/using-tfs-api-how-can-i-find-the-comments-which-were-made-on-a-code-review) provides a solution, you can check it:

You should be able to get to code review comments with functionality in the [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.aspx) namespace.

Specifically the comments are accessible via the [DiscussionThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.discussionthread.aspx) class. And you should be able to query discussions using [IDiscussionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.discussion.client.idiscussionmanager.aspx).

Code snippet is as below:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GetCodeReviewComments
{
   public class ExecuteQuery
    {
        public List<CodeReviewComment> GetCodeReviewComments(int workItemId)
        {
            List<CodeReviewComment> comments = new List<CodeReviewComment>();

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/defaultcollection");
            TeamFoundationDiscussionService service = new TeamFoundationDiscussionService();
            service.Initialize(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri));
            IDiscussionManager discussionManager = service.CreateDiscussionManager();

            IAsyncResult result = discussionManager.BeginQueryByCodeReviewRequest(workItemId, QueryStoreOptions.ServerAndLocal, new AsyncCallback(CallCompletedCallback), null);
            var output = discussionManager.EndQueryByCodeReviewRequest(result);

            foreach (DiscussionThread thread in output)
            {
                if (thread.RootComment != null)
                {
                    CodeReviewComment comment = new CodeReviewComment();
                    comment.Author = thread.RootComment.Author.DisplayName;
                    comment.Comment = thread.RootComment.Content;
                    comment.PublishDate = thread.RootComment.PublishedDate.ToShortDateString();
                    comment.ItemName = thread.ItemPath;
                    comments.Add(comment);
                    Console.WriteLine(comment.Comment);
                }
            }

            return comments;
        }

        static void CallCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            // Handle error conditions here
        }

        public class CodeReviewComment
        {
            public string Author { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }
            public string PublishDate { get; set; }
            public string ItemName { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cece Dong for your response. I have tried this with .net core conole app. Included "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" Version="16.153.0" and "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" Version="16.153.0" but none of them helped in resolving Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client.

Comment: You can try a .net framework console app, it would be working.

Comment: Sure, thank you so much, I will try with .net framework. I was wondering do we have any nuget package for .net core ?

Comment: Package "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient" is not compatible well with .net core. Some functions can be using in .net core app, but some can not. So it's recommended using .net framework app instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @Cece. Appreciate your time.